# Creating a custom validator function in Typescript for expressValidator class - parameter implicitly has 'any' type

Tags: typescript, express, express-validator

I want to create a custom validation function for express-validator in typescript by extending the 'body' object.

Looking at [the support page](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/guides/customizing) I copied and pasted

```
import { ExpressValidator } from 'express-validator';

const { body } = new ExpressValidator(
  {
    isPostID: async value => {
      // Verify if the value matches the post ID format
    },
  },
);
```

into VS code, but it comes up with "Parameter 'value' implicitly has 'any' type". Now I could just change this to `isPostID: async value:any => ...` but we do know though that the value passed will always be a string. I am struggling how to tell Typescript that this value will be a string. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What's the issue by doing `async (value: string)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just found that it actually works to define value as string: `isPostId: async (value: string) => ...`